# How to use PL/SQL in making the subject line of an email package variable?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

How can I make a variable subject of an email using PL/SQL?

Currently, I am using a constant string as the subject:

```
'Open Action items for review'
```

I need to modify it to:

```
'Open Action items for review Day 5'  -> If the action item is on 5th day since opening.
```

Or:

```
'Open Action items for review Day 10' -> If the action item is on 10th day since opening.
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Please post the code and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Example Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doit
    (days as VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN 
    RETURN 'Open Action items for review Day ' || days;
END doit;
```

How to call:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Subject: ' || doit(5));
END;
```